# Unable to use mysqldb in Python2 virtualenv on Fedora 27

Tags: python, fedora

My Python app that works on Fedora 26, does not work on Fedora 27.

I get this error:

```
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have created a new virtualenv after upgrading to Fedora 26. mariadb-devel is installed.

Answer (score 13):

This is a workaround:Add `unsigned int reconnect;` in line 344 of file: /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h. The struct should look like this:

```
  typedef struct st_mysql {
    NET         net;                    /* Communication parameters */
    void  *unused_0;
    char *host,*user,*passwd,*unix_socket,*server_version,*host_info;
    char *info,*db;
    const struct ma_charset_info_st *charset;      /* character set */
    MYSQL_FIELD *fields;
    MA_MEM_ROOT field_alloc;
    unsigned long long affected_rows;
    unsigned long long insert_id;               /* id if insert on table with NEXTNR */
    unsigned long long extra_info;              /* Used by mysqlshow */
    unsigned long thread_id;            /* Id for connection in server */
    unsigned long packet_length;
    unsigned int port;
    unsigned long client_flag;
    unsigned long server_capabilities;
    unsigned int protocol_version;
    unsigned int field_count;
    unsigned int server_status;
    unsigned int server_language;
    unsigned int warning_count;          /* warning count, added in 4.1 protocol */
    unsigned int reconnect;
    struct st_mysql_options options;
    enum mysql_status status;
    my_bool     free_me;                /* If free in mysql_close */
    my_bool     unused_1;
    char                scramble_buff[20+ 1];
    /* madded after 3.23.58 */
    my_bool       unused_2;
    void          *unused_3, *unused_4, *unused_5, *unused_6;
    LIST          *stmts;
    const struct  st_mariadb_methods *methods;
    void          *thd;
    my_bool       *unbuffered_fetch_owner;
    char          *info_buffer;
    struct st_mariadb_extension *extension;
} MYSQL;
```

Comment: Adding `unsigned int reconnect;` to `typedef struct st_mysql {}` totally worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

The Issue can be resolved by running the command

```
sed '/st_mysql_options options;/a unsigned int reconnect;' /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h -i.bkp
```

The fix is referred from https://github.com/DefectDojo/django-DefectDojo/issues/407

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall MySQL-python using this:

```
sudo python -m pip install --no-binary MySQL-python MySQL-python
```

Comment: I get this error while trying to install MySQL-Python with --no-binary flag.

Comment: _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    _mysql.c:2005:41: error: ‘MYSQL {aka struct st_mysql}’ has no member named ‘reconnect’
      if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                             ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/sudheer/workspace/pvenvs/p2s/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-NCecpJ/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-DUN97S-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sudheer/workspace/pvenvs/p2s/include/site/python2.7/MySQL-python" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NCecpJ/MySQL-python/

Comment: try to install `community-mysql-libs` using `dnf` then retry to run your application.

Comment: I have installed community-mysql-libs.x86_64 5.7.20-1.fc27 but it didn't help. I have the same error message as before.

Comment: I found a workaround for this issue. Remove mariadb* and instal mysql-community-server packages from Oracle. And then install MySQL-python via pip.